# Points of elliptic curves over different fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, extension-field, elliptic-curves, algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties

Let $f : E \to E'$ be an isogeny between elliptic curves (or abelian varieties), defined over a field $k$. Let $X$ be the kernel of $f$.
Let $L \supset k$ be an algebraically closed field.

Is it true that the natural map $X(\bar k) \to X(L)$ is a group isomorphism?

When $E' = E$ is any abelian variety and $f$ is the multiplication by an integer $m$ distinct from the characteristic of $k$, then $X(\bar k) \cong (\Bbb Z/m)^{2 dim(E)} \to X(L) \cong (\Bbb Z/m)^{2 dim(E)}$ is injective hence an isomorphism, because of cardinality. But what about more general cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition an isogeny has finite kernel, and the natural map is always injective, so I believe your argument would generalize.